# Full Work equation

Tags: thermodynamics, work

Basically when I was taking thermodynamics, teachers gave me the equation that the work done in a piston-cylinder system is equal to

### $$W=\pm\int PdV$$

and that you put **(+)** is because the cylinder is expanding and **(-)** if it is compressing, so if you do your integral and lets say that it is expanding (+ in the integral equation) and your result is positive too, the work done is going out(leaving) in the balance of energy equation (enters=leaves) but recently in thermofluids, my teacher gave us the equation $dW=PdV+VdP$

So now I have this exercise where form process 1 to 2 I have constant volume and different pressure (can be treated as a rigid tank) and from the equation we get 
\begin{align}
dW & =VdP  \\
\Rightarrow 
W &=\int VdP   =V \int dP 
=V\left(P_2-P_1\right) 
\end{align}
and I was wondering if you have also (+) and (-) as sign conventions before solving the integral (like $W=\pm\int PdV$and if do, when the work done is entering and where is leaving

Comment: You were taught wrong by your teachers.  The plus sign always applies.  So if the volume increases, positive work is done on the surroundings and if the volume decreases, dV is negative, and negative work is done on the surroundings.  The equation vdP only applies to an open system in which the kinetic energy of the fluid does not change, and the process is carried out reversibly and at steady state.

Comment: You are right but when using the integral with constant volume, if the sign is negative it means that the work done is going out or in?

Comment: Plus sign means work done by the system on the surroundings, and negative sign means work done by the surroundings on the system.

Comment: For either constant volume and constant pressure?

Comment: Are you familiar with the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it depends. If you decrease the volume at constant pressure you obtain
$$
W = \int_{V_1}^{V_2} P dV = P \cdot(V_2 - V_1)
$$
This expression is negative, because $V_1 > V_2$. If we instead increase the volume at constant pressure, the equation does not change. However,  the result is now positive, because  $V_1 < V_2$. So all signs are already included in the initial equation. You don't need a $\pm$ sign convention. The same is true for $VdP$.

Personally, I'm often getting confused with all the signs. Therefore, instead of blind faith I cross check my calculations, and fix the signs by hand -- in a test don't forget to state your argument. For all calculations I have done so far, this approach was fine. However, you need to make sure that you understand whether energy is **stored in** or **delivered by** the system.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't understand when the work done is going out or in. I understood the part of not putting the sign plus/minus but how do you know when work done is going out or in when you have the integral at constant volume?